# How to show an entire post content and not also the excerpt?

Tags: php, posts, theme-development, excerpt

I am pretty new in WordPress theme development and I have the following problem showing posts.

You can easily understand what I mean opening this link: http://lnx.asper-eritrea.com/25-ottobre-2013-roma-manifestazione-per-le-vittime-di-lampedusa-piazza-montecitorio-ore-10/

As you can see this is a post but this is not shown the entire post content but only approximately 3 rows of the entire post content (thene is printed the [...] that I think means that there are other text).

So into my **single.php** file (the one that show a single post content) I found:

```
    <header class="header-sezione">

        <?php
            // Start the Loop.
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                /*
                 * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
                 * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
                 * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

                // Previous/next post navigation.
                //twentyfourteen_post_nav();

                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
                    comments_template();
                }
            endwhile;
        ?>
    </header>
```

and this is the code of the **content.php** file (the one that show the post content):

```
<?php
/**
 * The default template for displaying content
 *
 * Used for both single and index/archive/search.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage AsperTheme
 * @since AsperTheme 1.0
 */
?>


<!-- Create a div with a unique ID thanks to the_ID() and semantic classes with post_class() 
     the_ID(): Print the numeric ID of the current post 
     post_class(): Print out and add various post-related classes to the div tag
-->
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>                              

    <header>
        <h2 class="entry-title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" 
                   title="<?php printf(__('Permalink to %s', 'your-theme'), the_title_attribute('echo=0')); ?>"
                   rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?>
                </a>

        </h2>

        <div class="entry-meta">
            <span class="meta-prep meta-prep-author"><?php _e('By ', 'your-theme'); ?></span>
            <span class="author vcard">
                <a class="url fn n" href="<?php echo get_author_link(false, $authordata -> ID, $authordata -> user_nicename); ?>" 
                                    title="<?php printf(__('View all posts by %s', 'your-theme'), $authordata -> display_name); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?>
                </a>
            </span>
            <span class="meta-sep"> | </span>
            <span class="meta-prep meta-prep-entry-date"><?php _e('Published ', 'your-theme'); ?></span>
            <span class="entry-date">
                <abbr class="published" title="<?php the_time('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO') ?>"><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></abbr>
            </span>
            <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'your-theme' ), "<span class=\"meta-sep\">|</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"edit-link\">", "</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t" ) ?>
         </div>     <!-- .entry-meta -->

    </header>

    <div class="entry-content">    
        <!--<?php the_content(__('Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&raquo;</span>', 'your-theme')); ?>-->
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <?php wp_link_pages('before=<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'your-theme' ) . '&after=</div>') ?>
    </div>      <!-- .entry-content -->

    <div class="entry-utility">
        <span class="cat-links">
            <span class="entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-cat-links"><?php _e('Posted in ', 'your-theme'); ?></span>
            <?php echo get_the_category_list(', '); ?>
        </span>
        <span class="meta-sep"> | </span>
        <?php the_tags( '<span class="tag-links"><span class="entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-tag-links">' . __('Tagged ', 'your-theme' ) . '</span>', ", ", "</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"meta-sep\">|</span>\n" ) ?>
            <span class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'your-theme' ), __( '1 Comment', 'your-theme' ), __( '% Comments', 'your-theme' ) ) ?></span>
            <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'your-theme' ), "<span class=\"meta-sep\">|</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"edit-link\">", "</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\n" ) ?>
    </div>      <!-- #entry-utility --> 

</article>  <!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

So I think that when I open a post I see only its beginning part could depend by the fact that into **content.php** I have:

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

Is it right? How can I show the entire post and not only its beginning part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in content.php change `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>` with

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

Or use this content.php file instead. I made changes in your content.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The default template for displaying content
 *
 * Used for both single and index/archive/search.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage AsperTheme
 * @since AsperTheme 1.0
 */
?>


<!-- Create a div with a unique ID thanks to the_ID() and semantic classes with post_class() 
     the_ID(): Print the numeric ID of the current post 
     post_class(): Print out and add various post-related classes to the div tag
-->
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>                              

    <header>
        <h2 class="entry-title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" 
                   title="<?php printf(__('Permalink to %s', 'your-theme'), the_title_attribute('echo=0')); ?>"
                   rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?>
                </a>

        </h2>

        <div class="entry-meta">
            <span class="meta-prep meta-prep-author"><?php _e('By ', 'your-theme'); ?></span>
            <span class="author vcard">
                <a class="url fn n" href="<?php echo get_author_link(false, $authordata -> ID, $authordata -> user_nicename); ?>" 
                                    title="<?php printf(__('View all posts by %s', 'your-theme'), $authordata -> display_name); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?>
                </a>
            </span>
            <span class="meta-sep"> | </span>
            <span class="meta-prep meta-prep-entry-date"><?php _e('Published ', 'your-theme'); ?></span>
            <span class="entry-date">
                <abbr class="published" title="<?php the_time('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO') ?>"><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></abbr>
            </span>
            <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'your-theme' ), "<span class=\"meta-sep\">|</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"edit-link\">", "</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t" ) ?>
         </div>     <!-- .entry-meta -->

    </header>

    <div class="entry-content">    
        <?php the_content(__('Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&raquo;</span>', 'your-theme')); ?>
        <?php // the_excerpt(); ?>
        <?php wp_link_pages('before=<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'your-theme' ) . '&after=</div>') ?>
    </div>      <!-- .entry-content -->

    <div class="entry-utility">
        <span class="cat-links">
            <span class="entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-cat-links"><?php _e('Posted in ', 'your-theme'); ?></span>
            <?php echo get_the_category_list(', '); ?>
        </span>
        <span class="meta-sep"> | </span>
        <?php the_tags( '<span class="tag-links"><span class="entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-tag-links">' . __('Tagged ', 'your-theme' ) . '</span>', ", ", "</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"meta-sep\">|</span>\n" ) ?>
            <span class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'your-theme' ), __( '1 Comment', 'your-theme' ), __( '% Comments', 'your-theme' ) ) ?></span>
            <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'your-theme' ), "<span class=\"meta-sep\">|</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"edit-link\">", "</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\n" ) ?>
    </div>      <!-- #entry-utility --> 

</article>  <!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```